# My array gives me a list of random letters, symbols and numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that takes a array of 7 random numbers from 1-10 and puts them in a array and prints it,but whenever I run it I get this same result [I@6d06d69c.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiversCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args){


    int[] myList = new int[7];

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int positionInArray = 0; positionInArray < myList.length; 
    positionInArray++) {
        int diverScore1 = rand.nextInt(10);
        myList[positionInArray] = diverScore1;
    }
    System.out.println(myList);
    }

}
```

Comment: use `Arrays.toString(myList)`

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(myList);` is evaluated like `myList.toString()` and it will only print out the memory address which you are getting (`[I@6d06d69c`).

So, you should use `Arrays.toString()` to print array for per item;

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList));
```

Comment: You should consider adding an **explanation**.

Comment: You have a point. Answer updated.